# Pyspark "wholeTextFiles() missing 1 required positional argument: 'path"

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, path

I want to read some csv files from a directory and save the name of the file using pyspark so I found this function (pyspark.SparkContext.wholeTextFiles) that does it.

However, I keep getting this message even though I made sure it gets a path.

```
wholeTextFiles() missing 1 required positional argument: 'path'
```

I can't find the solution.

```
import pyspark
from pathlib import Path

str_path = "/home/user/Docs"
path = Path(str_path)
rdd = pyspark.SparkContext.wholeTextFiles(path)
```

Comment: `path` in that method is a string, not a `pathlib.Path` object.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use [standard read](http://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameReader.csv) and [`input_file_name`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.input_file_name) to keep file name.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

(spark
  .read
  .csv('/home/user/Docs')
  .withColumn('file_name', F.input_file_name())
)
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention I need to save the names of the files

Comment: sure, check my update :)